# RSitecatalyst QueueRanked - eVar

Tags: r

I'm using the RSiteCatalyst package for R and I'm connecting to the API I'm having problems running the following code:

```
AffilateSignups <- QueueRanked("intuitca-qbo", "2013-08-01",format(Sys.Date(), format="%Y-%m-%d"), 
          c("instances","event60"),
          c("eVar74"), top="1000000",startingWith="1",segment_id="dw:814142")
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error in names(rows_df) <- elements_requested : 
>     'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

I have run the following:

```
    signupsWithChats <- 
  QueueRanked("intuitca-qbo", "2013-08-01",format(Sys.Date(), format="%Y-%m-%d"), 
              c("instances","event60"),
              c("evar74"), top="1000000",startingWith="1",segment_id="dsc:1335:330:64e7b994-b6f9-4758-a749-67ce0c8792f2")
```

And that doesn't seem to generate any errors. The only difference being that I'm calling in a prop versus an eVar.

Can't seem to find many examples, but would love it if someone could help me out.

Comment: I see `eVar74` and `evar74`, is the different spelling intentional?

Comment: That was me testing whether or not there is a difference.

I did however figure out the problem, my json file from the SiteCatalyst API was returning null values. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed starting with version 1.4.4 of RSiteCatalyst.

http://randyzwitch.com/rsitecatalyst-version-1-4-4-release-notes/